# Hilbert adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis

The Hilbert adjoint operator $T: \mathcal{H_1} \to \mathcal{H_2}$ is $T^*: \mathcal{H_2} \to \mathcal{H_1}$ such that for all $x \in \mathcal{H_1}$ and $y \in \mathcal{H_2}$ the inner product
$$\langle Tx, y\rangle = \langle x, T^*y \rangle $$
where $\mathcal{H_1}, \, \mathcal{H_2}$ are two different Hilbert spaces.
My question what the difference between the two theorems is? The first theorem tells us that the Hilbert adjoint operator if it does exist, it is a unique bounded linear operator with norm $\|T\| = \|T^*\|$. And the second theorem tells us that $T: \mathcal{H} \to \mathcal{H}$ is normal if and only if $\|Tx\| = \|T^*x\|$ for all $x \in \mathcal{H}$. I mean what is the normality for when we already known that the norm of an operator and its adoint are equal in Hilbert spaces?

Comment: What is the definition of normality which was given to you ? Usually an operator is defined as normal when it commutes with its adjojnt.

Comment: The equality $\|T\|=\|T^*\|$ holds for any bounded operator, not normal in particular.

Comment: There are two different norms here, even though the notations are similar. Let me write $\|T\|_\infty$ for the operator norm (measuring the size of an operator) and $\|x\|_2$ for the Hilbert space norm (measuring the size of a vector in the space). 

The norms are related, because by definition:
$$\|T\|_\infty := \sup_{\|x\|_2 = 1} \|Tx\|_2.$$

But saying that $\|Tx\|_2 = \|T^*x\|_2$ for *every* $x$ is much stronger than saying that the suprema are the same for $T$ and $T^*$. 

Consider $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$. The sup norm for each is 1 (they agree), but they rarely agree pointwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normality is a far stronger information than $||T||=||T^*||$.

Consider the function $\varphi_T : x \mapsto \frac{||T(x)||}{||x||}$ defined for all nonzero $x$. A consequence of normality is that $\varphi_T (x)=\varphi_{T^*}(x)$ for ALL $x\neq 0$. This need not be true at all when you only know that the operator norms of (T) and $T^*$ are equal! By definition, $||T||:= sup \ \varphi_T$. Intuitively, the amount of maximum stretching that the two operators do will be the same, while you could have that there are vectors that get stretched by $T$ and squished by $T^*$, or vice versa.

Example: consider $T: \mathbb{C}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^2$ which defined by the matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Thus $T^*$ is given by $$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
1 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Clearly $||T\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}||=1\neq2=||T^*\begin{pmatrix}
1\\
0\\
\end{pmatrix}||$ so $T$ is not normal.